# Error in compiling thesis, while using customized .bst file

Tags: bibliographies

I have created a customized .bst (meg1.bst) file for my thesis. however, on compiling the document, it gives error like **"You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry dietrich1990gems while executing---line 1178 of file meg1.bst"**. This entry correspond to a book. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
%%
%% This is file `meg1.bst',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% merlin.mbs  (with options: `seq-no,nm-init,ed-au,mcite,mct-6,mct-x6,dt-jnl,yr-par,xmth,yrp-x,dtbf,atit-u,jtit-x,trtit-b,volp-blk,jdt-p,jpg-1,pp-last,num-xser,ser-vol,ser-ed,pub-date,blk-com,ed,abr,xedn,and-xcom,etal-xc,etal-it,nfss,')
%% ----------------------------------------
%% ***  ***
%% 
%% Copyright 1994-2011 Patrick W Daly
 % ===============================================================
 % IMPORTANT NOTICE:
 % This bibliographic style (bst) file has been generated from one or
 % more master bibliographic style (mbs) files, listed above.
 %
 % This generated file can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
 % of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
 % archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
 % version 1 of the License, or any later version.
 % ===============================================================
 % Name and version information of the main mbs file:
 % \ProvidesFile{merlin.mbs}[2011/11/18 4.33 (PWD, AO, DPC)]
 %   For use with BibTeX version 0.99a or later
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------
 % This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
 % This is a numerical citation style, and as such is standard LaTeX.
 % It requires no extra package to interface to the main text.
 % The form of the \bibitem entries is
 %   \bibitem{key}...
 % Usage of \cite is as follows:
 %   \cite{key} ==>>          [#]
 %   \cite[chap. 2]{key} ==>> [#, chap. 2]
 % where # is a number determined by the ordering in the reference list.
 % The order in the reference list is that by which the works were originally
 %   cited in the text, or that in the database.
 %---------------------------------------------------------------------

ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  add.blank
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edn." }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pages" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "page" }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}

MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


STRINGS  { bibinfo}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  format.names
}
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  ""
  duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
  bolden
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      before.all 'output.state :=
    " (" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION{format.year}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {  "empty year in " cite$ *
       warning$
    }
    {
  "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { emphasize ", " * swap$ * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {first.page}
{ 't :=
  ""
    {  t empty$ not t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = not and }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          " " *
          format.year * " " *
          swap$
          first.page
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      {
          " " *
      }
      if$
      swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    { "" }
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      format.bvolume duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { ", " swap$ * * }
      if$
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          "," *
          " " *
          get.bbl.editor
          ", " *
          * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  key duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$
      journal duplicate$ empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref * warning$ }
        { "journal" bibinfo.check emphasize word.in swap$ * }
      if$
    }
    { word.in swap$ * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  "editor" bibinfo.check
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      "editor" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.etal
      emphasize
      *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              " " * bbl.etal
              emphasize
              *
            }
            {
             bbl.and space.word
              * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { series emphasize * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
            }
            { word.in swap$ * }
          if$
        }
        { word.in key * " " *}
      if$
    }
    { word.in format.crossref.editor * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      add.blank "(" *
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
      year empty$
        'skip$
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            'skip$
            { ", " swap$ * * }
          if$
          year "year" bibinfo.check
          bolden
          *
        }
      if$
      ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      format.publisher.address output
      format.edition output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.number.series output
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { output
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        {
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    {
      organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      address "address" bibinfo.check output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title output
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
    }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  editor empty$
    { publisher empty$
        'skip$
        {
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { publisher empty$
        {
          format.organization.address output }
        {
          organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
     }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.date output
  format.note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}
FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
%%
%% End of file `meg1.bst'.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. Please give the content of your bst file at line 1178 and before.

Comment: I have uploaded the same in form of coding